# Increment Invitations Counter with Devise Invitable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, devise-invitable

I am trying to test my application with Devise Invitable to run out of invitations (reach invitation limit) but I cannot get the invitations count to increment at all.  Does anyone know how this works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An idea would be is to add a column to the `devise invitable` table

so add a column `view_count`

and then in the controller that fires the call use

```
@var.increment!(:view_count)
```

Now you would be able to use the `view_count` and put a condition around it, as it would increment every time the action is called.

Comment: I added current_user.increment!(:invitations_count) to the create action in the invitations controller and that worked.  Thank you!!